# How to give permission to execute Eclipse application?

Tags: command-line, permissions, eclipse, chmod

This one has confused me for a couple of hours.
I know the command `sudo chmod +x file` to give executable permissions, and still I don't get my application to run.

For context, I installed Eclipse manually and in the `/opt/` folder.  I created a link to `/usr/bin/` and a `/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` file with the data to start from the launcher.

When I run `sudo eclipse` the program starts normally, but if I don't includo `sudo` then it gives me an error.  I tried giving permissions via `chmod +x` to all of the above, but I still get the error if I don't includo `sudo`.

This may be either a permission issue or an Eclipse issue.  There is an error for `Permission denied`, and also the message

```
The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Just FYI, one should *never* run graphical applications such as Eclipse using `sudo`. If it needs root permissions, you should use `gksudo` instead for avoiding to mess up permissions of your home directory. And you also have to know that if Eclipse runs as root, the programs you write and start with it run as root as well, which is most probably not desired and can be dangerous! Use root access as rarely as possible.

Comment: Good to know.  It did feel weird to have to start it like that, but then there's more issues that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A full step by step guide:

1. Remove your Eclipse installation

   ```
   sudo rm -r /opt/eclipse
   sudo rm /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   sudo rm /usr/bin/eclipse
   ```
2. Download eclipse [here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/), eg. [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 64-bit](https://eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/R/eclipse-jee-mars-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz).

   ```
   cd
   wget https://eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/R/eclipse-jee-mars-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
   ```
3. Extract the archive

   ```
   sudo tar xf eclipse-jee-mars-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz -C /opt
   ```
4. Create a desktop file

   ```
   nano ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```

   and add the configuration below

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Name=Eclipse JEE
   Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
   Icon=eclipse
   Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
   StartupNotify=true
   StartupWMClass=Eclipse-JEE
   ```

   `Icon=eclipse` takes the icon from your icon theme, if there is one. If not, use an absolute icon path.
5. Start eclipse via your launcher

Comment: Yup, this did it.  Using that installer had me go through a lot more.  
Thanks.

Comment: @Diego If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to [accept](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Comment: Minor details:  the icon didn't work as such, it's location is `opt/eclipse/icon.xpm`, the current version is 4.5.0.

Comment: `Icon=eclipse` takes the icon from your icon theme, if there is one. If not, use an absolute icon path.

Comment: The wget didn't work for me, but I managed to download the file from the site. This oomph installer just doesn't work, although on another computer, a few weeks ago, it did.

Comment: @Diego I converted the xpm into a jpg and it worked for me. Try `convert icon.xpm icon.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the diagnostics of the error `The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.` was clear:

> `/root/.p2/pool/plugins org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied`.

This is because I launched the eclipse installer with the sudo rights for getting access to `/opt`, where I wanted eclipse to be. As result, the installer placed a bunch of plug-ins under `/root` by some defaults of its own.

However, I circumvented this by

- creating an `/opt/eclipse` subdirectory that I owned. Say with `sudo mkdir /opt/eclipse && sudo chown -R user:user /etc/eclipse` (substitute `user` with your user name).
- launching `eclipse-installer` normally without sudo rights and having it finish its task
- reverting the ownership `sudo chown -R root:root /etc/eclipse`.

In the end I could start eclipse from the executable within that tree without sudo and without protest.

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864572/ for more context on this approach.